# React app cannot receive cookies from aws lambda backend

Tags: reactjs, cookies, aws-lambda, serverless-offline

I'm developing a server with AWS Lambda on Serverless Framework,
and using `serverless-offline` to test locally.
I just want to send cookies to my react app.

backend code.

```js
import { APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2 } from "aws-lambda";


const oneDayMillis = 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2 = async (event) => {
  const expires = new Date(Date.now() + oneDayMillis).toUTCString();
  return { 
    headers: {'Set-Cookie': `name=hardyeats; Path=/; Expires=${expires}; ; httponly;`},
    statusCode: 200 
  }
}
```

`serverless.ts` allowing cors.

```js
    httpApi: {
      cors: {
        allowedOrigins: ["${self:custom.env.${opt:stage}.ALLOWED_ORIGIN}"],
        allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type'],
        allowedMethods: ['GET','POST','PUT','DELETE'],
        allowCredentials: true
      }
    },
```

and react code, tiny.

```js
function Login() {


  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVER_URL}/oauth/login`)
    .then(res => console.log(res.headers))
  },[])

  return (
    <></>
  );
}
```

No matter how hard I try, I can't help but get empty headers.
How can my react app receive cookies from my backend? With POSTMAN, then I can receive cookies.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`sls offline` needs another option.

```
sls offline --disableCookieValidation
```

and frontend `fetch` needs `credentials` option.

```js
fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_SERVER_URL}/oauth/login`, {
    credentials: 'include'
})
```